# Spice pulsing sine source

Tags: simulation, spice, pspice, voltage-source

I've been trying to create a voltage source in Pspice with a 'pulsing' sine wave. I can't seem to get it working, I've tried inputting a sin function in a VPWL source.

An example of a waveform I try to create:

[image: waveform]

How I defined the VPWL source:

[image: source]

Comment: Why didn't the PWL source work? Please show us how you defined that source.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the VPWL source @ElliotAlderson

Comment: So why/how didn't this source work? What were your observations?

Comment: Why do not use a multiplier, between a sine wave and a rectangular wave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are 2 ways of making what is pictured ... [microcap 12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm) free.

[image]